# Having diffuculty with correctly reading inputs from console in Java

Tags: java, input

I am having problem to read inputs from console as stated below:

**Input:**
    The first line of input consists number of the test cases. The description of T test cases is as follows:
    The first line of each test case contains the size of the array, the second line has the elements of the array and the third line consists of the difference k.

```
Example:
Input:
2
5 
1 5 4 1 2
0
3 
1 5 3
2
```

Here is my code and its incorrect output:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T;
    T = input.nextInt();
    int[] k_holder = new int[T];
    int[] n_holder = new int[T];
    int[][] array  = new int[T][10000];

    for (int i=0; i<T; i++) { // length of test
        n_holder[i] = input.nextInt();
        String tmp[] = input.next().split(" ");

        for (int j=0;j<tmp.length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[j]);
        }

        int K = input.nextInt(); // difference 
        k_holder[i] = K;
    }
            System.out.println("===============");

    for (int i=0; i<T; i++) {
        System.out.println(n_holder[i]);

        for (int j=0; j<n_holder[i]; j++) {
            System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n" + k_holder[i]);
    }


Output:
2
5
1 5 4 1 2
===============
5
1 0 0 0 0 
54
1 0 0 0 
2
```

As soon as I type enter after array_line (in above case array_line is 1 5 4 1 2), I got strange output

Comment: What do you mean by array_line?

Comment: It is just a input line which contains some int numbers, and I should parse them before going to next iteration

Comment: `T`, `n` and `k` are cryptic names. Please give your identifiers descriptive names, so others can easily know what the purpose of those variables are.

Comment: @VinceEmigh they are just int variables, here the names are not important, but if you want to know I will give you link where you can find the descriptions of them : http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=413

Comment: Names are *always* important. `T` represents a `size` or `maxIndex`. `K` represents the `difference` (as stated by the comment, which wouldn't be needed if you had descriptive identifiers). It's important to us. You shouldn't force us to check out other sites to decode what you are showing us.

Comment: @VinceEmigh, I think you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you didn't provide your expected result. It is hard to tell what exactly you are going to do, the following are my suggestions.

1. add `input.nextLine();` after all your `nextInt()` statements,  `nextInt()` cannot consume the newline character(\n), therefore it needs `input.nextLine()` capture it, or the result will messed up.
2. use `String tmp[] = input.nextLine().split(" ");` to parse your space separated line, `next()` only handles the first token.

   import java.io.BufferedWriter;
       import java.io.FileWriter;
       import java.io.IOException;
       import java.time.LocalDateTime;
       import java.util.Scanner;

   ```
   public class Main{
       public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
           new Main().go();
       }

       public void go() throws IOException{
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           int T;
           T = input.nextInt();
           input.nextLine();
           System.out.println("T is " + T);
           int[] k_holder = new int[T];
           int[] n_holder = new int[T];
           int[][] array  = new int[T][10000];

           for (int i=0; i<T; i++) { // length of array
               n_holder[i] = input.nextInt();
               input.nextLine();
               System.out.println("n_holder[" +i + "] is " + n_holder[i]);

               String tmp[] = input.nextLine().split(" ");
              for(String e : tmp){
                   System.out.print(" " + e);
               }

               for (int j=0;j<tmp.length; j++) {
                   array[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[j]);
               }

               int K = input.nextInt(); // difference
               input.nextLine();
               k_holder[i] = K;
           }
           System.out.println("===============");

           for (int i=0; i<T; i++) {
               System.out.println(n_holder[i]);

               for (int j=0; j<n_holder[i]; j++) {
                   System.out.print(array[i][j] + " ");
               }
               System.out.print("\n" + k_holder[i]);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

My test:

```
2
T is 2
5
n_holder[0] is 5
1 5 4 1 3
 1 5 4 1 3
0
3
n_holder[1] is 3
1 5 3
 1 5 3
2
===============
5
1 5 4 1 3 
03
1 5 3 
2
```

Comment: @Humoyun glad it helps:)  next time add some comments to your code, it will help to understand your code

Comment: Surely :) , I just tried to be concise but instead it turned out to be unclear :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually ask a question here, but if you're wondering why your array output is 1 0 0 0 0 instead of 1 5 4 1 2, the reason is because you call

```
String tmp[] = input.next().split(" ");
```

instead of

```
String tmp[] = input.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Note that scanner is whitespace delimited by default. This means that `input.next()` only grabs the first token until it hits whitespace. So if your input "1 5 4 1 2", it's only grabbing the 1, and then doing some funky scanner slurp with the rest of the input. I believe it's even grabbing the rest of that line as the next inputs to scanner! So your `input.nextInt()` somehow ropes in 54, then loop back up, `input.next()` grabs 1, and the final `input.nextInt()` grabs 2 (hence the funny output, and observe we can sort of see 1 5 4 1 2 running down the side).

Why it decided that the nextInt() was 54 instead of 5 is not clear to me, though.

Comment: It gives : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: Looks like your split method is roping in empty strings, and those can't be formatted to ints. Parse those out.

Comment: @mwm314 OP also needs consumes the newline character each time after invoke `nextInt()`

Comment: @haifzhan Agreed, good call. I guess that's where that empty string popped out from :).