# Prevent going to next line after input in console

Tags: java, arrays, input

I have problem with my Java program. I am running the program on the console (`CMD`).

I would like, after I entered input, that the console stays on the same line (currently it goes to the next line automatically).

This is my current program:

```
int data[];
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
data = new int[10];
System.out.println("Please Insert Numbers : ");
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    data[i] = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("/t");
  }
```

How can I return to the start of the line instead of going to the next?

Comment: I think you need to be more specific, as it is not very clear from your question what needs to be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Having diffuculty with correctly reading inputs from console in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274469/having-diffuculty-with-correctly-reading-inputs-from-console-in-java)

Comment: please follow naming convention for array such as dataArray[] or dataList[]

Comment: If you want to read the whole input in the same line do not loop. Just read a string of numbers delimited by comma (",") or whitespaces (" "), then skip delimiters and build an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Insert Numbers Separated By Comma: ");
String input = in.nextLine();
input = input.replaceAll("\\s",""); //remove whitespaces
String[] numbers= input.split(",");  //build string array using ',' as delimiter between numbers
int data[]= Arrays.asList(numbers).stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(); //Available since Java8
```

Answer (score 0):

Like  Oscar Martinez said, you could read a string of numbers delimited by white space and build your integer array like this example (before parsing the string to int, I verify if the string can be converted to int or not using a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) )  :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int data[];
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        data = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Please Insert Numbers : ");
        String line = in.nextLine();
        String[] stringsNumber = line.split("\\s");
        for(int i=0;i<stringsNumber.length;i++){
            if(stringsNumber[i].matches("^\\d+$") && i<10){// \\d  is a regex to verify if s is a number

                data[i]= Integer.parseInt(stringsNumber[i]);

            }

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    }
}
```